# How to create a pluggable application in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an application which can be divided in multiple module with their own routing and all. And user can turn on and off these modules from application main module.

1. Do i have to load all the modules and dissable on the basis of if user has subscribed to it or not. I think it will slow down the application load because of loading all the modules code and injecting at application bootstrapping.
2. Are there any other alternative to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of enabled modules should be provided for main module:

```
var enabledModules = [...];

angular.module('app', ['thirdParty', 'app.common'].concat(enabledModules));
```

Obviously, `enabledModules` array can't be normally loaded with `$http`, because the application isn't bootstrapped at this point. XHR or server-side templating may be be used to define it.

Alternatively, a separate application can be used to load prerequisites. Due to the use of DI, it can be thoroughly tested.

```
angular.module('app', ['thirdParty', 'app.common']);

angular.module('appInitializer', [])
.factory('loader', ($http) => {
  return $http.get('enabled-modules').then((result) => result.data);
})
.factory('initializer', (loader, $document) => {
  return loader.then((enabledModules) => {
    $document.ready(() => {
      angular.bootstrap($document.find('body'), ['app'].concat(enabledModules));
    });
  });
});

angular.injector(['ng', 'appInitializer'])
.get('initializer')
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i have to create an server side login page Which will authenticate the user and on the basis of that i will create a dyanamic index.html and app.js which has the proper dependancies of application according to user.

Comment: It may be just dynamic html for convenience with `<script>`. Even if `app` module was defined in JS file before, it is overridden when it is redefined as `angular.module('app', [...])`.