# Cannot inject provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular 1.6

I develop a [dashboard application](https://github.com/sergibondarenko/angular-dashboard). There are two statically defined `ui.router` states for the registered dashboard components: `home-dashboard` and `other-dashboard`.

Now I want to define `ui.router` states dynamically based on dashboards data. For this, I do a loop inside `app.config`. But in order to get dashboards data, `StorageService` provider should be injected into the config.

The error received is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: StorageService
```

How to inject provider? Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

---

Also, I tried to move `$stateProvider` into `dashboardController`, the parent controller. By attaching it to app inside `app.config`, like `app.stateProvider = $stateProvider;` and exporting the app placing `return default app;` in the end of `app.js` file.

The error I got was `'return' outside of function`.

---

Provider `services/storage.service.js`(**it is a class which simulates API, in the future it will get data from DB**):

```
class Storage {

  constructor () {
      this.dashboards = {
        'home': {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Home',
        view: 'home',
        url: '/home',
        component: 'homeDashboard',
            widgets: [{
                col: 0,
                row: 0,
                sizeY: 1,
                sizeX: 1,
                name: "Widget 1"
            }, {
                col: 2,
                row: 1,
                sizeY: 1,
                sizeX: 1,
                name: "Widget 2"
            }]
        },
        'other': {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Other',
        view: 'other',
        url: '/other',
        component: 'otherDashboard',
            widgets: [{
                col: 1,
                row: 1,
                sizeY: 1,
                sizeX: 2,
                name: "Other Widget 1"
            }, {
                col: 1,
                row: 3,
                sizeY: 1,
                sizeX: 1,
                name: "Other Widget 2"
            }]
        }
      };
  }

  saveDashboards(dashboards) {
    this.dashboards = dashboards;
  }

  listDashboards() {
    return this.dashboards;
  }

  $get() {
    return this.dashboards;
  }
}

export { Storage };
```

**app.js**

```
import { DashboardCtrl } from './controllers/dashboardController';

import { homeDashboard } from './dashboards/home/homeDashboard.component';
import { otherDashboard } from './dashboards/other/otherDashboard.component';
import { aWidget } from './widgets/a_widget/aWidget.component';

import { Storage } from './services/storage.service.js';
import { Object2Array } from './filters/object2Array.js';

const app = angular.module('dashboardApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'gridster'
])
.controller('DashboardCtrl', DashboardCtrl)
.component('aWidget', aWidget)
.component('homeDashboard', homeDashboard)
.component('otherDashboard', otherDashboard)
//.factory('StorageService', () => new Storage())
.provider('StorageService', Storage)
.filter('object2Array', Object2Array);

app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, StorageService) {

  const dashboards = StorageService.listDashboards();

  _.forEach(dashboards, function (d) {
    $stateProvider.state({
      name: d.view,
      url: d.url,
      component: d.component
    });
  });

  /*
  const homeState = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    component: 'homeDashboard'
  };

  const otherState = {
    name: 'other',
    url: '/other',
    component: 'otherDashboard'
  };

  $stateProvider.state(homeState);  
  $stateProvider.state(otherState); 
   */

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

App tree:

```
../angular-dashboard/
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── dist
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   └── dashboardController.js
│   │   ├── dashboards
│   │   │   ├── home
│   │   │   │   ├── homeDashboard.component.js
│   │   │   │   ├── homeDashboard.controller.js
│   │   │   │   └── templates
│   │   │   │       └── homeDashboard.template.html
│   │   │   └── other
│   │   │       ├── otherDashboard.component.js
│   │   │       ├── otherDashboard.controller.js
│   │   │       └── templates
│   │   │           └── otherDashboard.template.html
│   │   ├── filters
│   │   │   └── object2Array.js
│   │   ├── services
│   │   │   └── storage.service.js
│   │   └── widgets
│   │       └── a_widget
│   │           ├── aWidget.component.js
│   │           ├── aWidget.controller.js
│   │           ├── aWidget.settings.controller.js
│   │           └── templates
│   │               ├── aWidget.settings.template.html
│   │               └── aWidget.template.html
│   ├── index.html
│   └── style
│       ├── style-common.css
│       └── style.css
└── webpack.config.js

15 directories, 22 files
```

UI look:
[image]

Comment: Basically same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150394/how-to-inject-provider-in-app-config . Wrong service type was chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to define routes directly in a controller.

First, we need to provide `$stateProvider` for the controller.

```
...
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  app.stateProvider = $stateProvider;
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});

export default app;
```

Second, we define states inside the controller.

```
import app from '../app';
...
const DashboardCtrl = function ($scope, $timeout, StorageService) {
...
  forEach($scope.dashboards, function (dashboard) {
    app.stateProvider.state({
      name: dashboard.name,
      url: dashboard.url,
      component: dashboard.component
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`StorageService` is `provider` service , and it is available as `StorageServiceProvider` service provider during config phase and as `StorageService` service instance during run phase.

When being injected as `StorageServiceProvider` it will be an instance of `Storage` class, and when being injected as `StorageService` it it will be return value of `$get` method (`dashboards` object).

`provider`, `factory` and `service` services are needed when service instance depends on other services. Otherwise `constant` or `value` service may be used.

`Storage` class is overkill because all it does is providing accessor methods for plain object. It can be `constant` service which will be available during both config and run phase under same name:

```
app.constant('StorageService', {
  home: { ... },
  ...
});
```

Comment: StorageService is a simulation of API. In the future I want to get the dasboards data from DB

Comment: Is it a bad practice to query DB in app.config? If yes, what should I do instead?

Comment: @trex This wasn't mentioned in the question. But yes. it is. DB request is asynchronous, isn't it? This will result in race condition, because app initialization will be completed before DB request completion. When this is data that should be used in app controllers only, this is done with route resolvers. But when this data is routing data that should be already available in `config`, it should be available before `angular.bootstrap` is called. I.e. you do DB request first, set StorageService `app.constant('StorageService', ...)` dynamically and only then call `angular.bootstrap`.

Comment: The DB requests will be asynchronous. Do you say I have to define my DB request service as app.constant?

Comment: This depends. You will have to define it's **result** as app.constant. What kind of DB request are we talking? Local IndexDb or remote API call?

Comment: Remote API call. The StorageService will return promise.

Comment: The Angular-friendly way is to make DB request on server side and provide DB req result in server-side page template as a global, i.e. `<script>window.ROUTING_DATA = ...</script>` and pick it up in Angular app. The alternative is to have **two** apps, the first one does DB request and bootstraps the second (main) one. See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41660722/3731501 . This design issue was fixed in Angular 2, but in AngularJS this is how it should be done.