# Difference between dependency injection by passing argument and by using angular.injector

Tags: angularjs

I had a use-case where I wanted to make the session timeout of the application configurable by making a call to REST api and get the value using $http. But as I found in this link [how to inject dependency into module.config(configFn) in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286588/how-to-inject-dependency-into-module-configconfigfn-in-angular) that services cannot be injected in config method, I have found this solution to make this work in the config:

```
var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
```

This is working fine, what is the difference between the two approaches and why this is working ? Also is there any limitation of using this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.injector` creates a new injector (application instance). It is misused most times and rarely ever needed in production.

It will have its own `$http`, `$rootScope`, `$q`, etc instances:

```
angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http') !== angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
```

The use of `angular.injector` in config block is an antipattern. It will result in untestable and potentially buggy code. `$http` request is asynchronous, application initialization will be completed first and likely result in race condition.

Most times when a need for `$http` in `config` appears, it should be performed in route resolver. If the response contains information that should be used to configure service providers and should be available in `config` block, it should be fetched prior to application bootstrap - in fact, there should be two applications, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41660722/3731501).

Comment: Thanks I will try the suggested method

Comment: In that link, will the variable 'enabledModules' be available in app.config since I need the values in app.config?

Comment: It won't. In that example data that was received (enabledModules) is a list of modules that should be bootstrapped. In your case it will be instead: `angular.module('app').constant('data', data); angular.bootstrap($document.find('body'), ['app'])`

Comment: But how will I get that data from REST service. I don't want to hard code it but get it from REST api call